# What happens here: Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;?

Tags: c#, .net

I seem to be a bit confused how the following call works:

```
string str = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;
```

I know it's the same as doing the following:

```
Process pvar = new Process();
ProcessModule pmvar = pvar.MainModule;
string str2 = pmvar.ModuleName;
```

But I need a detailed explanation how it's possible to ex. call the **MainModule** non-static property in the class **ProcessModule** since I haven't created an instanse of the **Process** class explicitly!

Does the **GetCurrentProcess()** method automatically create an instanse to work on, since it's not required to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*You* haven't created an instance of `Process`, but this returns one for you:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

That's very different from the `new Process()` call you've got in the second snippet. So your first statement is *actually* equivalent to:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
ProcessModule module = process.MainModule;
string moduleName = module.ModuleName;
```

[`GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx) returns a reference to a `Process` object representing the currently executing process.

Answer (score 2):

The call to [`GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx) return a [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) instance - your second codesnippet is not what really happens...

Answer (score 1):

`GetCurrentProcess` returns a reference to an instance. It could be a newly created instance, or a reference to an existing instance from some kind of cache. Anyways it is an instance, which can be used to call the `MainModule` getter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx), this is the behavior of GetCurrentProcess:

> Use this method to create a new Process instance and associate it with the process resource on the local computer.